# Nonlinear Difference Equations

Tags: plotting, difference-equations, modeling

How can I plot the nonlinear difference equations?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `RecurrenceTable`? Does this suit your needs: https://pastebin.com/upWrGA6B ?

Comment: $x_n$, $x$, $y_n$, $y$ coexist in the system, is this intended or typo?

Comment: finity, I need to see the structure around (0,0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For discrete data you can do it by "hand". Here is how to proceed.
First we need some discrete data. You may make a Table, where you give explicit x/y values. E.g.

```
Table[x^2, {x,{1,2,3}}]
```

This would result in:

```
{1,4,9}
```

With this you may create data describing the velocity field of the form {point, velocity-vector}. E.g.

```
dat = Flatten[
   Table[{{x, 
      y}, {.01 (0.4 x^3 - .2 y^2 x + 1.1 y^3), .01 (-9 x^3 + 
         9 x y^2 + .6 y^3)}}, {x, Table[x, {x, -3, 3, 1}]}, {y, 
     Table[y, {y, -2, 2, .8}]}], 1];
```

Now we wrap Arrow[{point,point+arrow}] around each data tuple and finally Graphics. This gives you a graphics with narrow displaying the local velocities:

```
   Graphics[ Arrow[{#[[1]], #[[1]] + #[[2]]}] & /@ dat, Axes -> True ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "plot the nonlinear difference equations"? I assume that you want, analogously to differential equations, to get a "velocity field". Towards this aim, you  need to calculate the **difference** between x/y at n and n+1. Therefore you must not include the first x and y.

In addition, your code has several syntax errors, I cleaned it up, see below.

```
StreamPlot[{.01 (0.4 x^3 - .2 y^2  x + 1.1 y^3), .01 (-9 x^3 + 
     9 x y^2 + .6 y^3)}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Daniel. do you think this code work with difference equation StreamPlot[{.01 (0.4 x^3 - .2 y^2  x + 1.1 y^3), .01 (-9 x^3 + 
     9 x y^2 + .6 y^3)}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by: "this code work with difference equation"

Comment: Daniel, I mean this code StreamPlot[{.01 (0.4 x^3 - .2 y^2  x + 1.1 y^3), .01 (-9 x^3 + 
     9 x y^2 + .6 y^3)}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]. does this code work  with my system( difference equation)? as I know this code just only for differentail equation . Thank u

Comment: Yes, this code:  StreamPlot[{.01 (0.4 x^3 - .2 y^2 x + 1.1 y^3), .01 (-9 x^3 + 9 x y^2 + .6 y^3)}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}] works on my PC (MMA 12.1 Windows 10). If it works on your, you have to try yourself.

Comment: Daniel Huber, but the system I have is discrete. If the system is continuous , then your code is right.... I mean How I plot this discrete system? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how useful this is, but how about plotting what happens to a grid of values in one time step?

```
map[{x_, y_}] := {
  x + .01 (0.4 x^3 - .2 y^2 x + 1.1 y^3), 
  y + .01 (-9 x^3 + 9 x y^2 + .6 y^3)};

GraphicsRow[{
  Show[
   ListLinePlot[
    Table[Table[{x, y}, {y, -3, 3, 0.25}], {x, -3, 3, 0.25}], 
    PlotStyle -> Table[RGBColor[1 - x, 0, x], {x, 0, 1, 1/25}]],
   ListLinePlot[
    Table[Table[{x, y}, {x, -3, 3, 0.25}], {y, -3, 3, 0.25}], 
    PlotStyle -> Table[RGBColor[1 - x, 0, x], {x, 0, 1, 1/25}]],
   PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, AxesLabel -> {"x_t", "y_t"}
   ],
  Show[
   ListLinePlot[
    Table[map /@ Table[{x, y}, {y, -3, 3, 0.25}], {x, -3, 3, 0.25}], 
    PlotStyle -> Table[RGBColor[1 - x, 0, x], {x, 0, 1, 1/25}]],
   ListLinePlot[
    Table[map /@ Table[{x, y}, {x, -3, 3, 0.25}], {y, -3, 3, 0.25}], 
    PlotStyle -> Table[RGBColor[1 - x, 0, x], {x, 0, 1, 1/25}]],
   PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, AxesLabel -> {"x_t+1", "y_t+1"}
   ]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Anyhow, looks kind of cool!